# Disabling SQL Server's caching through .NET code

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I am currently calling up several stored procedures in some .NET code, `SqlConnection`. I'd like to disable the caching done by SQL Server, so that I can measure performance periodically (I'm gonna be comparing it to another server that likely won't have any cached data either). Is this possible to do without modifying the sprocs?

This is the code that I am currently using:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(/* connection string goes here */)) {

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(procName, connection);
    command.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
    command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    connection.Open();

    SqlDataReader r = command.ExecuteReader();
    // todo: read data here
    r.Close();
    connection.Close();
}
```

Comment: This is hard. Shouldn't you measure cached performance anyway because it is more representative?

Comment: How about just sending `dbcc dropcleanbuffers` prior to your query?

Comment: This is a bad idea and you most probably don't want to do this; doubly so in production. But if you must, `dbcc dropcleanbuffers` and `dbcc freeproccache` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms187762.aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174283.aspx

Comment: If performance matters - you are measuring it so I guess it does - you should be all cached, all the time. First buy enough RAM.

Comment: @LesH, that's the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing, by "cacheing" here I'm assuming you're referring to the Execution Plan Cache. Once SQL Server figures out the best order to execute your statements, it stores it for a while. This problem is commonly known as "Parameter Sniffing". This is what you clear when you run `dbcc freeproccache`. Unfortunately, that's an admin-privileged command and it affects all connections.

The root of the problem is that your SQL probably performs differently with a different set of parameters. SQL Server will only store the execution plan of the first execution it sees and the parameters associated with it. So if the arguments on first execution are good for the common case, your app will perform fine. But once in a while, the wrong arguments will get used on first execution and your entire application can perform poorly.

There are a number of ways to optimize your SQL statement to reduce the impact of this, but it's not completely avoidable.

1. Generate the SQL dynamically - You take the performance hit of generating a query plan on each execution, but this may be worth it if using the wrong execution plan causes your query to never return. I suggest this path, though it is more cumbersome. I found `SET STATISTICS TIME ON` and SQL Profiler helpful in reducing the plan generation time. The biggest improvement came from using 3-part naming (`owner.schema.table`) for the tables.
2. Specify a "good set" of initial parameters for your query with query hints.

```sql
SELECT Col1, Col2
FROM dbo.MySchema.MyTab
WHERE Col1=@Parameter
OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR (@Parameter='value'));
```

This link describe the [parameter sniffing problem](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/06/the-elephant-and-the-mouse-or-parameter-sniffing-in-sql-server/) fairly well. This was a bigger problem in SQL 2005. Later versions of SQL did a better job of avoiding this.